# Type narrowing error if discriminant property is union

Tags: typescript

I wrote something like the following code in TypeScript.
The type `ABCD` is like a state object and its `kind` property represents the type of the state. Because some of them (`kind` is `'a'` or `'b'`) have a common additional property `extra`, I wrote a common type of them as `AB`. The others don't have an extra property, so I merged them as `CD` as below.

```
type AB = {
  kind: 'a' | 'b',
  extra: string
};

type CD = {
  kind: 'c' | 'd'
};

type ABCD = AB | CD;

function printExtra(x: ABCD) {
  if (x.kind === 'c' || x.kind === 'd') return;
  console.log(x.extra);
}
```

The function `printExtra` prints `extra` property if `kind` is neither `'c'` nor `'d'`.
I was convinced the compilation will pass because that if statement asserts `x` is not `CD` and because `AB` is the only candidate for the type, obviously `x` is `AB`. But the TypeScript compiler failed to compile with the following message.

> Property 'extra' does not exist on type 'ABCD'.
> Property 'extra' does not exist on type 'CD'.

Why does the above code failed to compile? I have also tried the following code and confirmed it compiles successfully, but if possible I don't want to use it because it is somewhat redundant in my project.

```
type A = { kind: 'a', extra: string };
type B = { kind: 'b', extra: string };
type C = { kind: 'c' };
type D = { kind: 'd' };

type ABCD = A | B | C | D;
```

Comment: You can always help the compiler a bit by defining `function isCd( x: ABCD ): x is CD { return x.kind === 'c' || x.kind === 'd'; }`. As for why it happens, no idea.

Comment: `type ABCD` can be eathier `AB` or `CD`. when `type ABCD = AB` you can use `x.extra` because `AB` has `extra` but when `type ABCD = CD` you cant call `x.extra` because `CD` does not include `extra`.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your code to check the other way around

```
 function printExtra(x: ABCD) {
    if (x.kind === 'a' || x.kind === 'b') {
        console.log(x.extra); // no error
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your logic a step further:

```
type A = { kind: 'a', extra: string };
type B = { kind: 'b', extra: string };
type C = { kind: 'c' };
type D = { kind: 'd' };

type AB = A | B;
type CD = C | D;

type ABCD = AB | CD;
```

So then this would also work:

```
type AB = ({ kind: 'a' } | { kind: 'b' }) & { extra: string };
type CD = { kind: 'c' } | { kind: 'd' };

type ABCD = AB | CD;
```

Let's make this a bit less verbose:

```
type Kind<T extends string> = { [K in T]: { kind: K } }[T];

type AB = Kind<'a' | 'b'> & { extra: string };
type CD = Kind<'c' | 'd'>;

type ABCD = AB | CD;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glgOwCYB4AqUIA9gWQZyn2ACdEBzAPigF4oBvKAbRikSjQF0AuBqAa0RJerAL5RRTLgG4AULNCQoAQQBCtWEJQByAIbaoAHyjaARtuoAyPtlK7exMgnIS5i6AGEAIhvjIdAMYGxtpIFnIK4NBq3hpqRlDeEQBmAK4IAcBwAPYIUGBOwACiOCS6ABRYvDFeAJQMslBsyVCVAHSCyLQ0dNpBRsZYHULdvWH1JBDAqSQIck0BufjZADYQbSvZ5O22ZbVyokA)

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative way to do it. You can use [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```js
type AB = {
    kind: 'a' | 'b',
    extra: string
};

type CD = {
    kind: 'c' | 'd'
};

type ABCD = AB | CD;

function assertIsAB(x: ABCD): asserts x is AB {
    if (x.kind !== 'a' && x.kind !== 'b') {
        throw new Error("Not a string!");
    }
}


function printExtra(x: ABCD) {
    assertIsAB(x);
    const result = x; // AB
    console.log(x.extra); // ok
}
```

Drawback: you should handle error

Personally, I prefer second approach, with typeguards. It is much safer:

```js
type AB = {
    kind: 'a' | 'b',
    extra: string
};

type CD = {
    kind: 'c' | 'd'
};

type ABCD = AB | CD;

const isAB = (x: ABCD): x is AB => x.kind === 'a' || x.kind === 'b'

function printExtra(x: ABCD) {
    if (isAB(x)) {
        const result = x.extra; // AB
    }
}
```